How to build a Vue web component which reflects an internal state as an attribute?
I am building a web component input which looks like this with Vue 3:
<my-input value="Search"></my-input>

How can I make sure that the value attribute is always equivalent to the current internal value?

Vue 3 is not really made with web components in mind. All Vue-internal APIs like defineModel(), defineExpose() or defineEmits() will not be properly translated when using defineCustomElement().
You can however solve this with custom logic:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, computed } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  value?: string;
}>();

const $search = ref();
const instance = computed(() => ($input.value?.getRootNode() as ShadowRoot)?.host);

const query = ref(props.value ?? '');
watch(query, () => instance.value.setAttribute('value', query.value));
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model.trim="query" ref="$input">
</template>

